# Angular form is not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to update my form in angular but i'm getting error.
here is my angular code.

```
app.controller('userEditController', [
  '$scope', '$resource', 'EditUser', '$routeParams', '$location', function($scope, $resource, EditUser, $routeParams, $location) {
console.log($routeParams.id);
$scope.user = EditUser.show({
  id: $routeParams.id
});
 $scope.updateUser = function() {
    userData = JSON.stringify($scope.user); 

    $scope.user = JSON.parse(userData);
    console.log($scope.user['id']);
    console.log($scope.user);

    $('#loading').removeClass('hidden');
    return EditUser.update({
        id: $scope.user['id']
    }, {
        user: userData
    }, (function() {
        $('#loading').addClass('hidden');
        return $location.path('/users');
    }), function(error) {
        return console.log(error);
    });
  };
 }
 ]);
```

But when am trying with any Api tool its working fine.
kindly guide me.

> Object {data: "org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyE…ustomerportal.rest.data.CustomerUserData["user"])", status: 400, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "Bad Request"}config: Objectdata: "org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "user" (Class com.datacode2.customerportal.rest.data.CustomerUserData), not marked as ignorable↵ at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@167ab67; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.datacode2.customerportal.rest.data.CustomerUserData["user"])"headers: function (name) {status: 400statusText: "Bad Request"**proto**: Object

Here is image of error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzK8C.png)

Comment: The error is clear: bad request. Maybe has something to do headers being different in both cases. Just compare headers when request works and when it fails.

Comment: did you check http://i.stack.imgur.com/DzK8C.png

Comment: It doesn't seem that the error is on the client. I guess EditUser.update is making a request that returns 400. Maybe there is an error in that function, can you add EditUser service?. And why do you stringify and parse the same object?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the problem is not from the front-end side. The service that saves the user is failing and returning a bad request.

```
Objectdata: "org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "user"
```

It seems you're using Jackson in the back-end to save the user. When you try to update the user, you're sending two elements:

```
return EditUser.update({
    id: $scope.user['id']
}, {
    user: userData
}
```

Your back-end code doesn't complain about the "id" attribute, but it does complain about the "user" attribute, so you have to check what actually your service expects to receive. Probably it doesn't expect to receive the userData, at least not in the way you're sending it. Feel free to post your service back-end code.